# Mint 18.3 resumes from suspend/hibernate but the screen doesn't come back on

Tags: nvidia

I have a very nice HP OMEN X 17-ap010nr laptop (16GB RAM, 7700HQ, GTX 1070 mobile, the works).  This particular model does not support Optimus.  (maybe it does but I don't really want to dig around in HP's really confusingly organized BIOS right now to enable the IGP - I am no stranger to BIOS but HP's is particularly...odd - you put the boot order *where?*).  I dual boot Windows and Linux Mint 18.3 KDE.

It works well, but whenever the machine suspends or hibernates (really hibernates, not KDE's sorry excuse), it will resume, some sounds continue to play, the lights and fans come on, all is good... except the monitor doesn't.  I have not found any way out of this state (mind you, not that I've looked very hard) besides holding down the power button.

Rarely (I have only experienced this twice; both instances have involved plugging in an external monitor) the screen will come back on and I can continue to work.  The first time, the external monitor was plugged in when the laptop went to sleep.  I swiped the trackpad to wake it up and the external monitor woke up, but not the internal one.  This was encouraging but problematic as the windows and taskbar that were on the internal monitor were not moved.   The second time, the machine went to sleep, I plugged in an external monitor and then moved the trackpad.  The internal display woke up as it should.  I nearly died of shock.

I've had this problem since I installed Linux.  Windows is of course unaffected.

This seems to be a fairly common problem, but none of the existing solutions I've tried have worked.  Proprietary or open source graphics driver does not matter, it happens on both.  I'd try Optimus but as I said I don't think my laptop supports it.  `sudo apt install laptop-mode-tools` had no effect besides causing my keyboard to stop working the second it completed.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I have done some more testing with the external monitor thing.  The first time the machine suspends after a cold boot, the machine comes back up just fine if an external monitor is connected (both internal and external monitors come on) *even if the external monitor was connected while the machine was asleep*.  If an external monitor is not connected when the system resumes, the internal monitor will not wake.  If an external monitor is plugged in after the machine wakes, *it* will turn on and show the login screen, but the internal monitor remains ark.  I can type my password, log in, and go back to work.  However the internal monitor is still seen as a display even when it's off, and any windows that were on that monitor remain there until I close the lid of the laptop, at which point they move to the external monitor.  (I must say, I really like that feature of KDE.)  Opening the lid again moves them back.  The SECOND time the machine resumes from suspend after a cold boot (i.e. if any of the above have happened and i suspend the machine *again*), neither monitor will not wake no matter what.    Furthermore closing the lid without an external monitor connected while in this state will NOT put the machine to sleep.  Pressing Alt+Print screen+B to reset still works; after it reboots everything is back to normal.